# How to convert Juniper config to json

Tags: json

We need to convert Juniper config to json is there any Juniper command for this or how should we write a small ruby code to convert default juniper config into json.

Answer (score 1):

After Junos release 14.2, `show config | display json` command is available.
http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/en_US/junos14.2/topics/concept/junos-cli-pipe-filter-functions-overview.html

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no command to convert to JSON, but perhaps you could read it in XML format then convert the XML to JSON using Ruby?

JunOS

```
show configuration | display xml
```

Ruby

```
Hash.from_xml('...').to_json
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody is looking:
https://beastiebytes.com/public_files/juniper_hash.rb

```
require 'json'
require 'juniper_hash'
JuniperHash.get_hash(File.open('juniper.conf').read).to_json
```

Answer (score 0):

In configuration mode you can do this : 
 show |display json

If you want to store it in a file 
 show |display json |save file.cfg