# How to convert Juniper config backup file

Tags: python, juniper, junos-automation

We have a system that keeps a backup of the configuration of Juniper's devices

We need to load this file and transform it into a more readable format, such as XML or Json

Is it possible to do it with Python?

We found a way to do it in Ruby, but we need it in Python, any suggestions?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28905687/4371496

Comment: How do you store the backup config? If you are looking for xml or json type at end, shouldn't the backup be done in these formats itself?

Comment: the backup file is generated by an external software called Orion, this uses the default format of Juniper, we know that we can go to the device and save a new file with the XML or JSON format, but what we need is to analyze the history of the devices, which unfortunately this file is already saved badly.